# Formik with FetchBaseQuery

Tags: reactjs, formik, rtk-query

I have a form built with Formik. The form has an initial input box in which user is supposed to enter his username, if the username is valid then the API will return the subsequent details for the user which I need to pre-fill further in the form.

Is there a better way to handle it in Formik.
I explored and find out I can use `initialValues` but I need to initialise it a bit later.

The form looks something like the following, but has a lot more details to display
[image]

Also, if the user doesn't have a username then also we can let the user enter details manually & click on submit.

I tried the following, but now I believe it is not an optimal solution to the problem, can you please help me how to take care of such use cases

```
 const response = useQuery(username,{skip});
 const userData: any = response?.data;
 const formikRef = useRef<FormikProps<FormikValues>>(null);
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
        formikRef.current?.setFieldValue("name", userData.name);
        formikRef.current?.setFieldValue("detail1",userData.detail1);
        formikRef.current?.setFieldValue("detail2",userData.detail2);
      } 
  }, [agreementLineData]);
 return (
    <Formik
      innerRef={formikRef}
      initialValues={{
        username: "",
        name: "",
        detail1: "",
        detail2: ""
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {})
      {({ values, submitForm, setFieldValue }) => {
        return (
           <Form>
             <FormField label="Username">
                 <Input value={values.username}/>
                 <Button variant="primary">Validate</Button>
             </FormField>
             <FormField label="Name">
                 <Input value={values.name} onChange={(e) => {}}/>
             </FormField>
             <FormField label="Details 1">
                 <Input value={values.detail1} disabled={true}/>
             </FormField>
             <FormField label="Details 2">
                 <Input value={values.detail2} disabled={true}/>
             </FormField>
          </Form>
    </Formik>
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `initialValues` of Formik to populate your form's input rather than having each one use `setFieldValue`.

All you need to do for the above is to add `enableReinitialize` prop.

It will re-initialize the form whenever your `initialValues` are updated. This way your values would be populated properly.

Just play with `initialValues` and you should be good to go.